# Number of colour palettes when branding a company

Tags: color, color-theory, branding

**Context**

I'm creating the branding for a company. The company's main product is a web portal where customers have a collection of functionalities. For the portal I'm using a lot of soft colours to create a calm and trustworthy environment (by color association).

However, I'm not sure if this color palette will work when using the branding for promotion material like flyers, brochures and commercials. In that case I want more popping colours to get potential user's attention and direct this attention to call-to-action (to register with the company, for example).

**Question**

What would be the best thing to do in this case? Either change the first colour palette to have a multi-functional palette (just the one), or is it OK to have multiple color palettes as a company?

I'm currently going for the soft color palette for the company's products and a variation on that one with more contrast for branding and promotion.

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you have a **single** branding palette. That branding palette may include one or two colors for specific uses. So you may have a largely pastel palette, with one brighter callout color.

You don't rewrite the entire brand merely because it's used in a different location/medium. That kind of defeats the purpose of a brand color guide.